# node.js forever, how can I set the limit file-size of forver debug log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I run node.js forever with option to log output debug -d and -l options. I known forever use winston for logging. How can I limit the file size of the LOGFILE (pass option maxsize and maxFiles to winston) without modifying forever.js. Is there forever already have this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option unfortunately. Also I don't think it would be optimal to do so, imagine something checking the file size after each log or after a number of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll use logrotate.